# Spring Security: Custom CSRF Implementation by extending CsrfRepository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, csrf

I am trying to create a customized CSRF implementation in my Spring Boot application by implementing the `CsrfRepository` interface provided by Spring Security.

Below is how my custom repository looks like:

```
public class CustomCookieCsrfTokenRepository implements CsrfTokenRepository {

    static final String DEFAULT_CSRF_COOKIE_NAME = "XSRF-TOKEN";

    static final String DEFAULT_CSRF_PARAMETER_NAME = "_csrf";

    static final String DEFAULT_CSRF_HEADER_NAME = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";

    @Override
    public CsrfToken generateToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return new DefaultCsrfToken(this.DEFAULT_CSRF_HEADER_NAME, this.DEFAULT_CSRF_PARAMETER_NAME, createNewToken());
    }

    @Override
    public void saveToken(CsrfToken token, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        String tokenValue = token == null ? "" : token.getToken();
        Cookie cookie = new Cookie(this.DEFAULT_CSRF_COOKIE_NAME, tokenValue);
        cookie.setSecure(request.isSecure());
        response.addCookie(cookie);
    }

    @Override
    public CsrfToken loadToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, this.DEFAULT_CSRF_COOKIE_NAME);
        if (cookie == null) {
            return null;
        }
        String token = cookie.getValue();
        if (!StringUtils.hasLength(token)) {
            return null;
        }
        return new DefaultCsrfToken(this.DEFAULT_CSRF_HEADER_NAME, this.DEFAULT_CSRF_PARAMETER_NAME, token);
    }

    private String createNewToken() {
        String unsignedToken = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        return RSAUtil.signMessage(unsignedToken, privateKey);
    }
}
```

**QUESTION**: As you can see, I want to sign my cookie value using a private key and validate it using a public key. The question is where should this verification logic take place? I am guessing `loadToken()` method can have the logic to validate the signature. Is this the correct place or should it take place elsewhere?

Can someone provide some snippets or samples on how and where to handle this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the verification logic should be in **generateToken(HttpServletRequest request)** of your custom CsrfTokenRepository implementation.  
The **saveToken(CsrfToken token, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)** should save the token (or delete the saved token when the passed 'token' param is null) and **loadToken(HttpServletRequest request)**  should return the existing saved token (which was saved by saveToken method) for the current request/session;

```
@Component
public class CustomCsrfTokenRepository implements CsrfTokenRepository {

    static final String DEFAULT_CSRF_PARAMETER_NAME = "_csrf";
    static final String DEFAULT_CSRF_HEADER_NAME = "X-XSRF-TOKEN";

    private String parameterName = DEFAULT_CSRF_PARAMETER_NAME;

    private String headerName = DEFAULT_CSRF_HEADER_NAME;

    private String cookieName = "USER_INFO";

    private static final String DEFAULT_CSRF_TOKEN_ATTR_NAME = CustomCsrfTokenRepository2.class
        .getName().concat(".CSRF_TOKEN");

    private String sessionAttributeName = DEFAULT_CSRF_TOKEN_ATTR_NAME;

    @Override
    public CsrfToken generateToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        Cookie cookie = WebUtils.getCookie(request, this.cookieName);
        if (cookie == null) {
            return new DefaultCsrfToken(this.headerName, this.parameterName,
                createNewToken());
        }
        String cookieValue = cookie.getValue();
        String token = cookieValue.split("\\|")[0];
        if (!StringUtils.hasLength(token)) {
            return new DefaultCsrfToken(this.headerName, this.parameterName,
                createNewToken());
        }
        return new DefaultCsrfToken(this.headerName, this.parameterName, token);
    }

    @Override
    public void saveToken(CsrfToken token, HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response) {
        if (token == null) {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
            if (session != null) {
                session.removeAttribute(this.sessionAttributeName);
            }
        }
        else {
            HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute(this.sessionAttributeName, token);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public CsrfToken loadToken(HttpServletRequest request) {
        HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);
        if (session == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return (CsrfToken) session.getAttribute(this.sessionAttributeName);
    }

    private String createNewToken() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }

}
```

And you need to set your customCsrfRepoImpl bean in HttpSecurity configuration as shown below

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfigurarion extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private CsrfTokenRepository customCsrfTokenRepository; //your custom csrfToken repository impl class 

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {

        httpSecurity
            .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(customCsrfTokenRepository) //set your custom csrf impl in httpSecurity
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(permittedUrlsArr).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
            .logout()

    }

}
```